# Login con react y axios, no se crea el token

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-axios

Estoy tratando de hacer un login con Laravel en el back y React en el front.

Este es el error en consola al ingresar los datos
[image: Este es el error en consola al ingresar los datos]

Se supone que en la pestaña "Aplication" de la consola debería aparecerme el token, pero no aparece nada.

Así tengo mi login.jsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "../api/axios";

const Login = () => {
  const[email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const[password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate  = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try{
      await axios.post('/login', {email, password});
      setEmail("")
      setPassword("")
      navigate("/");
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Este es el github del autor del video de youtube que estoy siguiendo donde tiene la aplicación en un estado más avanzado:

https://github.com/codewithtonyofficial/react-authentication-with-breeze-api/blob/main/src/pages/Login.jsx#L131

¿Qué podría estar mal?

Aquí lo que dice en la pestaña Network de la consola

[image: Aquí lo que dice en la pestaña Network de la consola:]

Aquí el contenido de mi axios.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://laravel-react-api.test",
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

Aquí el repositorio donde tengo todo el front:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/react-breeze-api-

Y en este otro tengo todo el back:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/laravel-react-api

Comment: Puedes proporcionar mas información? 

puedes verificar la data que se esta enviando en la pestaña del navegador que se llama red. hay puedes ver las peticiones que se estan realizando, y confirmas los datos que se estan enviando.?

Comment: Ahora edito con más información el post inicial.

Comment: El token debe de estar en la respuesta del json de tu controlador del login.